# How to Rowfilter in c# datagrid using textbox with MS Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

I tried watching tutorials on youtube. C# keeps on responding 'missing operand' hope someone can help me

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = "select * from Table2 where Last_Name ='" + textBox12 + "'";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Are you using winforms? if so, tag it.

Comment: Please post more details such as table schema and code that is not working. Please refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean exactly by Rowfilter? Add some code if you have an error.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, its hard to predict your code. If it is WinForms application and you have one TextBox (lets say named SearchTextBox) and dataGridView (lets say called dataGridView1) and you have column called FirstName in your dataGridView1 (also in dataTable), your code should looks like this:

```
private void SearchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bd = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource;
    var dt = (DataTable)bd.DataSource;
    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("FirstName like '%{0}%'", SearchTextBox.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));    
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource'.'

Comment: You already have DataTable called dt. You added code snippet after I posted this reply. Anyway, after your command da.Fill(dt), you should use command to filter row 
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Last_Name like '%{0}%'", SearchTextBox.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));